# Can a digital watermark be still extracted from the reprinted digital watermarked image?

Tags: steganography

If I'm able to extract a watermark from a printed watermarked image, will I be still able to extract the watermark information if I first scan the printed watermark image and reprint it (make a copy of printed watermarked image with high quality scanner and printer)?

Comment: That will depend on the deployed watermark technique.

Comment: I'm confused.  A watermark is designed to be detectable and/or not easily obfuscated.  That's kinda the opposite of steganography isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. But it's very difficult to resist the printing process.

You can find useful information here:
http://jultika.oulu.fi/files/isbn9789526200583.pdf

Comment: I've already gone through the pdf. Can you please elaborate it further more "it's very difficult to resist the printing process."! I just want to know whether print-cam robust watermarking technique developed by Anu Pramila makes a printed watermarked image copy-proof or not?

Comment: I mean that there are additional problems to those that occur with watermarking in digital images. For example the distortion added by the devices: printer, scanner, etc or the effect of the print material: ink density, lighting conditions ...

Comment: So it'll be very difficult to extract watermark from copied watermarked image due to scanning original watermarked image and printing the scanned image, right? @DanielLerch

Comment: Yes! and also because you have to align properly the image. This is easier with a scanner but it's hard if you use a camera.

Comment: [READING WATERMARKS WITH A CAMERA PHONE FROM PRINTED IMAGES](http://jultika.oulu.fi/files/isbn9789526218052.pdf) I am following this paper. Can you tell me whether this watermarking technique can detect the copied watermark printed image or not? As I want to use the watermarking technique described in this paper for product authentication to fight counterfeiting of products.